# arrow key navigation problem in html/jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have an application which has 3X4 matrix of images using arrow key(up,right,top,bottom) i move among images. if iamge is focused for 1sec that particular image will zoomin. as focus moves to next cell image zoomout. initially focus will be in first cell.

now my problem are:
1) even though i have navigation module (as i said initially focus in first cell of table) using arrow keys to move from initial cell is not working. first i need to use tab only then i can move using arrow keys

2)say for example focus is in initial cell if dont move focus any where else for 1sec firstimage should zoomin. which is not happening in my case.

3) say for example im in first cell and if i press up (according to my application ) it should remain in same cell as there is no image to jump. but where as in my application focus goes off. again i have to reload page in order to get focus.how do i over come this issue.

could some one help me solve this issue. have look at demo i have enclosed.

thanks in advance

[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rashmi/zLNkj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest consolidating any code that requires jQuery into the `$(document).ready(function () { // your code here });` function. This should eliminate dependency issues. Also, you should consider declaring any variables that might be used throughout your app, in the first part of your ready function. I have a working example from your code [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/AfjTP/2/). Hope this helps.

Edit: I updated the jsfiddle to help you with the upkey issue you are experiencing. Take a look at the code under your upkey event.

Comment: can you suggest me something on 3rd issue i had mentioned.

Comment: I edited my jsfiddle and updated the link in my post to help you with that issue. Here is the updated link again, http://www.jsfiddle.net/AfjTP/2/ 
The same method I used there could be easily copied to your down events, looking for lower TRs.

Comment: thanks alot. surely i will go through your code. i need same condition to be applied even for last row in table. i will try manipulating code as my requirement if any doubt i will ask for your help. thanks alot :)

Comment: hey i have one small issue. say focus in 1st row and first cell pressing left makes focus invisible sililarlly if focus is in 3rd row last cell pressing right key makes focus invisible. how to fix this issue. can you help me if you dont mind?????

Comment: Use the same kind of conditional I setup for your "up" key event for the rest of your key events.

Comment: Deferring execution until the `onload` even fires is definitely important in most cases, and until you're adequately familiar with how pages are loaded, you should probably default to always using this technique.